# Don't know how to use target="_blank" in code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I currently use a download button whose HTML and Script is like this

```html
<button id="downloadbuttonx" onclick="generate()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Download</button>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="downloadingx" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Redirecting...</a> Script

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  function generate() {
    var e, n = document.getElementById("downloadingx"),
      t = document.getElementById("downloadbuttonx"),
      a = document.getElementById("downloadingx").href,
      l = 4,
      d = document.createElement("span");
    n.parentNode.replaceChild(d, n), e = setInterval(function() {
      --l < 0 ? (d.parentNode.replaceChild(n, d), clearInterval(e), window.location.replace(a), n.style.display = "inline") : (d.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'/> Redirecting to download page in " + l.toString() + " seconds.", t.style.display = "none")
    }, 1e3)
  }
  //]]>
</script>
```

It works like, When download button is clicked, 4 seconds timer began and when finished, Link is opened in the same page.

I want that link to be opened in a new Tab, instead of a same page and I have no idea how to do it.

Please help.

Comment: Change `window.location.replace(a)` to `window.open(a)`

Comment: Hey Rory McCrossan! Thank you so much. ☺♥
That works for me. ☺♥
Thanks alot ☺♥

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the behaviour from redirecting the page to opening a new tab, change `window.location.replace(a)` in your code to `window.open(a)`.

Answer (score -1):

The target="_blank" is an attribute that corresponds to an "a" element. It triggers the link to be opened in a new tab if the link element is clicked.

Comment: Please provide useful piece of code for Asker and his question 'how to use in the code' not what is it for...